$H \leqslant (\Bbb{Z}/n)^*$ the square roots of $1$, with $n$ squarefree; what's size of pseudocoset $kH\subset \Bbb{Z}/n$ where $k$ is any integer
Consider the ring $\Bbb{Z}/n$ for square-free $n$.  Then the multiplicative subgroup $H \leqslant (\Bbb{Z}/n)^*$ given by $H = \{ x \in \Bbb{Z}/n : x^2 = 1 \pmod n\}$ has size exactly $|H| = 2^{\omega(n) - [2\mid n]}$ where $[2\mid n]$ is $1$ if $2$ divides $n$, else $0$.
So since the size of $|H|$ is known, we already know the size of $uH$ (as a subset of residues in $\Bbb{Z}/n$) is also $|H|$ whenever $u$ is a unit, this is because multiplication by the unit is an invertible function.
But what about when $\gcd(k,n) \neq 1$, or in other words $k\in \Bbb{Z}$ is not a unit modulo $n$.  Then what is the size of the pseudocoset $kH$?

Attempt.
$$
k h_1 = k h_2 \pmod n, \ h_1, h_2 \in H \\
\iff \\
k(h_1 - h_2) = 0 \text{ or } h_1 - h_2 \in \ker \\
\text{ of the } \Bbb{Z}\text{-module map } f(x) = kx : \Bbb{Z}/n \to \Bbb{Z}/n
$$
My conclusion is confusion. 

Might a group action help?  The group we set to $H$ and the set is all $\Bbb{Z}$ modulo $n$ so $\Bbb{Z}/n$ since we know that the action of $k \in \Bbb{Z}$ will start repeating itself modularly.
Thus $H\times R \to R$ is the action with $R = \Bbb{Z}/n$.  Now how can we use group action theory to count what we need?

I think looking at ring theory could help: zero divisors and all, and the ring of integers mod n - that sort of thing.  I am a little busy, so I'll refine my idea later.

@Shaun Thanks mon .  I added some tags.  This is quite related deeply to the TPC.  However, it's interesting on it's own, because we don't normally consider these psuedo cosets.

Related (principal ideals).

You could look at solutions to the polynomial $x^2-1=0$ over $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$.

Related.

@Shaun I think I might have solved, it but the solution is quite involved and will need help checking it in the answer I write.  Let me know if it makes sense

Is "psuedocoset"  correct, or perhaps a typo for "pseudocoset" (as in, not really a coset)?

I don't think your formula is correct. Say $n=3$. Then there are exactly two elements in $H$, namely $1$ and $-1$. But your formula says that the number of elements of $H$ is $2^{3-0} = 2^3=8$. In fact, since $2^{n-1}\gt n$ for all $n\geq 3$, how could a subset of $(\mathbb{Z}/n) $ possibly have that many elements?

Rather, the correct value has to do with the prime factorization of $n$. If $n=p_1\cdots p_r$ with $p_i$ distinct primes, then the number of solutions is $2^r$ if $2\nmid n$, and $2^{r-1}$ if $2\mid n$.

@Shaun Arturo Magidin solved it first, but I'm not 100% sure we got it.  Care to take a look at our proofs?

I trust Arturo's judgement, @DanielDonnelly.  Both your proofs seem fine enough to me, though I haven't looked too closely.

The size of $H$ depends on the number of prime factors of $n$. If $n=p_1\cdots p_r$, with $p_1\lt p_2\lt\cdots\lt p_r$ distinct primes, then $|H|=2^r$ if $p_1\neq 2$, and $|H|=2^{r-1}$ if $p_1=2$. In other words, the formula is, using your notation,
$$|H| = 2^{r-[2\mid n]},$$
where $r$ is the number of distinct primes that divide $n$.
By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, we know that
$$\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \cong (\mathbb{Z}/p_1\mathbb{Z})\times\cdots\times (\mathbb{Z}/p_r\mathbb{Z}).$$
Let $\gcd(k,n)=t$, and let $I$ be the indices $i$, $1\leq i\leq r$, such that $p_i\mid t$. Then if $x\in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, we have that the projection of $kx$ in the $p_j$th factor is $0$ if and only if either $j\in I$, or else if both $j\notin I$ and $x\equiv 0\pmod{p_j}$.
So let $u_1,u_2\in H$. Then $ku_1\equiv ku_2\pmod{n}$ if and only if $u_1\equiv u_2\pmod{p_j}$ for all $j\notin I$.
Consider first the case where $2\nmid n$. Let $s=r-|I|$. For each $j\notin I$, pick $a_j\in\{\pm 1\}$. Then all $u\in H$ with $u\equiv a_j\pmod{p_j}$, $j\notin I$, are mapped to the same element by the function $x\mapsto kx$, and these are all the elements of $H$ mapped to that image. So we get one distinct image for each such choice, and those are all the images. There are $2^s$ choices, so $|kH|=2^s$ in this case.
If $2\mid n$, then it doesn't matter whether $2\mid t$ or not, since any two $u\in H$ have the same image when projected to the $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. So proceeding as above, we need to make selections in $r-|I|$ components if $2\mid \gcd(n,k)$, and in $r-(|I|+1)$ if $2\nmid\gcd(n,k)$. So let $s=r-(|I|+1-[2\mid\gcd(n,k)])$. Then $kH$ will have $2^s$ elements.
So we want $2^{r-|I|}$ when $2\nmid n$, and we want $2^{r-|I|}$ if $2\mid \gcd(n,k)$, and $2^{r-(|I|+1)}$ if $2\mid n$ but $2\nmid k$. This amounts to $2^{r-(|I|+[2\mid n]-[2\mid \gcd(n,k)]}$.
So:

Let $n$ be a squarefree integer, and let $H$ consist of the elements of $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ whose square is $1$.
Let $r$ be the number of distinct prime factors of $n$;  then $|H|=2^{r-[2\mid n]}$.
Given $k$, let $u$ be the number of distinct prime factors of $\gcd(k,n)$, and let
$s=
r-(u+[2\mid n]-[2\mid \gcd(n,k)])$. Then $|kH| = 2^s$, with each fiber of the same size.

Example. Let $n=2\times 3\times 5\times 7= 210$, and let $k=20$.  Then $r=4$, so $|H|=2^{4-[2\mid 210]} = 2^3 = 8$. Indeed,
$$H=\{1, 29, 41, 71, 139, 169, 181, 209\}.$$
$\gcd(k,n) = \gcd(20,210) = 10 = 2\times 5$, so $I=\{2,5\}$, hence $s=4-(|I|+[2\mid 210]-[2\mid \gcd(210,20)]) = 4-(2+1-1) = 2$. So the claim is that $kH$ has exactly $2^s = 2^2=4$ elements, hence each fiber has $2$ elements (that is, each image is achieved twice). Indeed,
$$\begin{align*}
20H &= \{20\bmod 210,580\bmod 210,820\bmod 210,1420\bmod 210,\\
&\qquad\qquad2780\bmod 210,3380\bmod 210,3620\bmod 210,4180\bmod 210\} \\
&= \{20, 160, 190, 160, 50, 20, 50, 190\} = \{20, 50, 160,190\}.
\end{align*}$$
Now, if $k=63=3^2\times 7$ instead, so $\gcd(n,k)=21$, we have $u=2$, $[2\mid n]=1$ and $[2\mid\gcd(k,n)]=0$, so $s=4-(2+1-0) = 1$. So now the claim is that the image has exactly $2^1=2$ elements. Indeed,
$$\begin{align*}
63H &= \{63\bmod 210, 1827\bmod 210,2583\bmod 210,4473\bmod 210,8757\bmod 210,\\
&\qquad\qquad 10647\bmod 210,11403\bmod 210,13167\bmod 210\}\\
&=\{63, 147, 63, 63, 63, 147, 147, 63, 147\} = \{63,147\}.
\end{align*}$$

Nevermind.  I was using the formula, but I didn't use it correctly, so my other calc is wrong.  I checked this one.  Would you still like me to post a code verify answer?

@DanielDonnelly That's up to you.

Okay, I will post some code.  It's amazing that we nailed this problem with a closed form :)

Let $\gcd(k,n) = d$.  Then by the Orbit-Stabilizer theorem we have that $|kH| = |\text{Orb}(k)|  =|H|/\text{Stab}(k)$ where $\text{Stab}(k) = \{ h \in H : hk = k \pmod n\}$.  One such example is $11\cdot 3 = 33 = 3 \pmod {15}$.
Let $m = \frac{n}{d}$.
But $h \in H$ and
$$\begin{align*}
hk = k \pmod n  &\iff (h-1)k = 0 \pmod n \\ &\iff h -1 = 0 \pmod m \\ &\iff h = 1 \pmod m \\ &\iff h = 1 + mz \text{ for some z } \in \Bbb{Z}\end{align*}
$$
But remember we also need $h$ to be in $H$, so how many $z$ solve:
$$\begin{align*}
(1 + mz)^2 = 1 \pmod n 
&\iff 1 + 2mz + m^2z^2 = 1 \pmod n\\
&\iff mz(2 + mz) = 0 \pmod n \\
\end{align*}$$
Now we don't need to solve for the roots- that's hard , because $d$ is not a prime number and so you'd need CRT.  But from CRT familiarity one can easily derive that we simply take the number of solutions modulo each hypothetical prime $q \mid d$ and count its solutions.  The product of the sizes of doing this for each prime $q \mid d$ equals the total for the case of composite modulus $d$.
So modulo $q = 2 \mid d$ we have, that because $m$ is a unit modulo any $q \mid d$:
$$
\begin{align*}
m^2 z^2 = 0 \pmod {2} 
&\iff 
z^2 = 0 \pmod {2} \\
&\iff 
z = 0\end{align*}
$$
So there is only a single solution modulo $q = 2$, but if $q \gt 2, q \mid d$:
$$
z = 0 \text{, or, } 
z  = \frac{-2}{m} \pmod {q} \\ \textbf{(by solving the other factor in the equation)}
$$
It's possible that these two could be equal.  But that could only happen if:
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{-2}{m} = 0 \pmod {q} 
&\iff -2 = 0 \pmod q \\
&\iff 
q = 2\end{align*}
$$
But we already handled that case above.  Thus modulo all odd primes $q \gt 2$ the equation has exactly 2 solutions.  All together we can summarize that modulo $n$ there are:
$$
2^{\omega(d) - [2\mid d]}
$$
But in the original group $H$ there are $2^{\omega(n)-[2\mid n].}$
Thus the answer I'm after is:
$$
|kH| = \frac{2^{\omega(n)- [2\mid n]}}{2^{\omega(d) - [2\mid d]}} = 2^{\omega(n/d) - [2\mid n] + [2\mid d]}, \\ \ \\
\textbf{ Where, } 
d := \gcd(k,n)
$$
Is the exact size of $kH$ as a subset of residues in $\Bbb{Z}/n$; by the Orbit-Stabilizer theorem first mentioned.  $\blacksquare$

This answer has to agree with @ArturoMagidin's

@ArturoMagidin You get the idea of what this approach is trying to do; so do you see where I fumbled?

I haven't read it through. I went to the final formula to see if it agreed with mine, and immediately noticed that what you had written cannot possibly be true for the reason stated above.

We are still getting different answers. In my  notation, $\omega(n)=r$ and $\omega(d)=u$, so $\omega(n/d) = r-u$. If $n$ is odd, your formula gives $2^{r-(r-u)}=2^u$, but my formula gives $2^{r-u}$. If $n$ is even and $d$ is odd, your formula gives $2^{r-1-(r-u)+1} = 2^u$, but mine gives $2^{r-(u+1)}$. When both $n$ and $d$ are even, your formula gives $2^{r-1-(r-u)} = 2^{u-1}$, and mine gives $2^{r-(u+1-1)} = 2^{r-u}$.

@ArturoMagidin still correcting; please standby :)

I see some mistakes. Where it says "So modulo $q=2$..." you claim that $d^2z^2\equiv 0\pmod{2}$ requires $z\equiv 0\pmod{2}$, but that is not true: you could have $d$ even, in which case $d^2z^2\equiv 0\pmod{2}$ regardless of $z$. You have the same issue with $q$ odd: if $q\nmid d$, then your calculations are correct. But if $q\mid d$, then $d^2z^2\equiv 0\pmod{q}$ for all $z$.

@ArturoMagidin it's all messed up. But once I correct it it will be a beautiful theorem I think, for these mysterious psuedocosets.

With your notation, my formula is $2^{\omega(\frac{n}{d}) + [2\mid d] - [2\mid n]}$.

@ArturoMagidin I know it's cool that we're both about to get two proofs to the same result.  We're pros    No AI can beat us (yet)!  I can derive it just as I have it almost exactly.  I just need to put in a few things and change $\frac{n}{d}$ for $d$ in places like you were saying and what I'm seeing so far is exact match with yours

@ArturoMagidin can I publish this result after verifying it?  The quantity appears when you generalize a TPC counter function on a growing interval to other types of $2k$ separated prime averages.

I confess I don't know what "TPC counter function" is. But it looks like you got the answer on your own with a different argument than mine (though they are of course connected). So it's really up to you; if you want to thrown an acknowledgement my way, feel free; you can use the url for the answer as a citation.

@ArturoMagidin Yes, yours will go first, then mine.  And I'll try to parse yours if I ever do publish.  It's about counting twin primes in an interval.  There's some finite groups involved.

Not sure what "yours will go first, then mine" refers to.

@ArturoMagidin further explaination / intros of the proofs.
